# Kernel crash in hardware interrupt; core dump shows process context

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, netbsd

This is for NetBSD on MIPS processor, but answer for Linux is also welcome.

I see that an interrupt occurred while receiving a network packet.
This hardware interrupt sees a TLB miss on store operation and kernel crashed.
When I see the core-dump, gdb points to LWP of a process (lets say ProcA).

I am assuming that, this hardware interrupt may have preempted the ProcA and started execution on ProcA's kernel stack.
Though in the stack frame I don't see anything from ProcA, what I don't understand is why gdb still points to ProcA.

Comment: Perhaps you would get answers if you ask the question on NetBSD's mailing lists, tech-kern@ perhaps.